# Custom RouteMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hi I have to route an old path, that was containing the old webform, to my new controller.

I tried this:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "DownloadLink",
            "products/pippo/download/{*catchall}",
            new { controller = "Downloads", action = "Index"} 
            );
```

To have my controller called with http://mysite.com/products/pippo/download/ but what I receive it's a 404 Status Code, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `DownloadLink` route registration before all the other routes registrations in your Global.asax `RegisterRoutes` method.

Comment: I've tested it and this work for me. The order of registration is important and determine the way MVC engine resolves routes. Maybe a syntax problem, check the name of the controller...

Comment: Ok, you're right but it works for http://mysite.com/products/pippo/download/something and not for http://mysite.com/products/pippo/download/, I need more the second one how do I have to change the MapRoute definition?